# when syncing state trie of an Ethereum node, why not start from a recent block to reduce syncing time

Tags: go-ethereum, fast-sync, state-trie

as explained in this issue: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16218#issuecomment-371454280

when we are syncing an eth node, firstly it downloads the blocks, then the states, the first part take way less time than the second, so that's why when we are syncing, if we see syncing info like this, we probably still have to wait for a long time before the node finish syncing:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "result": {
        "currentBlock": "0x7b9f62",
        "highestBlock": "0x7b9fc5",
        "knownStates": "0xbdc375b",
        "pulledStates": "0xbdc331d",
        "startingBlock": "0x0"
    }
}
```

In my case, downloading the block took me roughly 2 days, and for the states trie, 1 week has passed, and it's still syncing.

there are 2 things I am wondering:

1. why there isn't a progress bar showing the progress of the downloading of state trie?
2. why not start download a state trie from recent block, and then updating the trie based on that, it would save a lot of time.